# How do I retrieve Scheduler row height?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar-scheduler

Using Scheduler, here are partly my fullCalendar options:

```
                header:
                   {
                      left: 'prev,next',
                      center: 'title',
                      right: 'timelineMonth,timelineYear'
                    },
                    defaultView: 'timelineMonth',           
                    resourceLabelText:' ',
                    resourceAreaWidth  : "10%", // (etc)
```

I need to compute the `height:` option based on the number of rows in my ressource array (or events array —I am not sure).

How do I retrieve the Scheduler standard row heigth?

**Edition:** I am going to use Scheduler with the `defaultView: 'timelineMonth'` option, i.e. in 'timeline' view. But Scheduler, if the `height` option is not set, extends down the display zone far beyond the number of rows to be displayed. I want to check this behaviour by computing the necessary height.

Comment: why do you need to compute the height? If you don't specify one, fullCalendar will work out the height needed for the calendar based on how many resources you've got on display. I'm not sure what the reason for this is? Perhaps I missed something. Anyway if you want to know the default height, just look at the CSS. If it's easier, render a calendar, right click on a resource row, inspect it and see what height it is.

Comment: Hum… as to inspecting rows I spent an hour on it, without a clue. There seems to be much dynamic calculations, e.g.:$(".fc-rows table tbody tr .fc-widget-content div").addClass('fc-resized-row');
Since Fullcalendar documentation states that the height value can be returned by a function, I need the row height for the said function.

Comment: But again, why do you need to compute the height in the first place, and particular based on the resource height? fullCalendar will basically do this for you already

Comment: Haha, you are out for it all! Very good, I am going to edit my post presently.